# A confusion about BFS algorithm

Tags: java, graph

The following code is used to traverse a graph and print the elements in vertices ... but this code is suitable if the elements are numbers .... suppose that these elements are string or characters ... what changes can I do to print string or characters

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
  
// This class represents a directed graph using adjacency list 
// representation 
class Graph 
{ 
    private int V;   // No. of vertices 
    private LinkedList<Integer> adj[]; //Adjacency Lists 
  
    // Constructor 
    Graph(int v) 
    { 
        V = v; 
        adj = new LinkedList[v]; 
        for (int i=0; i<v; ++i) 
            adj[i] = new LinkedList(); 
    } 
  
    // Function to add an edge into the graph 
    void addEdge(int v,int w) 
    { 
        adj[v].add(w); 
    } 
  
    // prints BFS traversal from a given source s 
    void BFS(int s) 
    { 
        // Mark all the vertices as not visited(By default 
        // set as false) 
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[V]; 
  
        // Create a queue for BFS 
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
  
        // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it 
        visited[s]=true; 
        queue.add(s); 
  
        while (queue.size() != 0) 
        { 
            // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it 
            s = queue.poll(); 
            System.out.print(s+" "); 
  
            // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s 
            // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it 
            // visited and enqueue it 
            Iterator<Integer> i = adj[s].listIterator(); 
            while (i.hasNext()) 
            { 
                int n = i.next(); 
                if (!visited[n]) 
                { 
                    visited[n] = true; 
                    queue.add(n); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is, why does the content of the nodes matter?

Comment: If you only want to print the contents of the nodes then you just need to change <Integer> to <Object>, that way you will be able to add to queue what you want. But if you need to do more complex operations with the contents then you should create your own class which will be able to store different types and override toString() method there

Answer (score 0):

Like Szprota21 says you need to incorporate generics into your `Graph` class:

```java
class Graph<T> 
{ 
    private int V;   // No. of vertices 
    private LinkedList<T> adj[]; //Adjacency Lists 
  
    // Constructor 
    Graph(int v) 
    { 
        V = v; 
        adj = new LinkedList<T>[]; 
        for (int i=0; i<v; ++i) 
            adj[i] = new LinkedList<T>(); 
    } 

    // Continue using T
```

Which allows you to use:

```java
Graph<Integer> intgraph = new Graph<Integer>(5);
Graph<String> intgraph = new Graph<String>(5);
Graph<Character> intgraph = new Graph<Character>(5);
```

And just like previously mentioned use:

```java
T value = queue.poll();
value.toString();
```

Comment: How do you map T objects to array indices in this setup? You may want to switch from using an array of List to something like a `Map<T, List<T>>` here.

Comment: This was to just get them started with types other than Integer; I agree based on his other requirements changes will need to be made.